# Designate a Server as a Preferred Bridgehead Server using Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016

I am setting up a new domain controller (Microsoft Windows 2016 server). How would I specify it as primary bridgehead server using powershell. All articles which I have read show how this is accomplished using GUI not commandline